# Does a function ( $f(x)$ )is convex iff $f''(x)>0$?

Tags: functions, online-resources

I don't know when a function is convex. My documents from different resources tell me different answers. One of them told me that a function $f(x)$ is convex if and only if $f ''(x)>0$, but another told me it must be $f''(x)<0$. I need your help, please tell me the truth. Thanks

Comment: If the function is twice differentiable (and defined on an interval), it is convex if and only if $f''(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x$. The strict inequality $f''(x) > 0$ is sufficient - but not necessary - for _strict convexity_ of $f$. If $f''(x) < 0$, then $f$ is strictly concave.

Comment: What happens if you apply your criteria on a classic example of function, as $f(x)=x^2$? Note that there are different terminologies for convex functions: convex/concave, concave upward/concave downward,... And also variations of the definition of convex (is a constant function convex?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convex is for $f^{\prime\prime} \geq 0$. Remember it that way: you want the graph of the function to look like a "valley," i.e. to have a shape similar to the parabola $y=x^2$.

If the function is twice differentiable, for that, the slope of the function has to become greater and greater, i.e. the derivative $f^\prime$ has to be monotone non-decreasing. But this in turn means the second derivative $f^{\prime\prime}$ (the derivative of $f^\prime$) must be non-negative.

(For $f^{\prime\prime} \leq 0$, the function is *concave*. If $f^{\prime\prime} > 0$, it is *strictly* convex, and if $f^{\prime\prime} < 0$, it is *strictly* concave.)

**Caveat:** this is when the function is twice differentiable (and on an interval). Convexity and concavity are defined even if $f$ is not differentiable (and a fortiori twice differentiable): the definition is a bit more general, but in the case of $f$ twice differentiable they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function but the Wiki in my language (Not English) tell me the reverse. And I become worried with my knowledge.

Comment: @DDK This is strange... which Wikipedia is it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to fix the Wikipedia in my language, but they seems not to be accepted. They have been turned into the older version. And I must ask to prove that my knowledge is true.